# Updating Solana NFT metadata on chain

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I am trying to figure out how to update a Solana NFT's metadata on the chain. The NFT is already minted and I do not have access to the original json file which was used to create the NFT, which is therefore why I need to update it on chain. What do I need to have in order to update the Solana NFT? What software do I need? and how do I use it?

I have been struggling to figure this out so if anyone could give me some advice, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all nft data is stored on chain. E.g. attributes and the image url see off chain.

So first make sure to know which data you want to update exactly.

If you just want to update a single nft is easiest To go to a website like https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/ and update the  metadata there. If you want to also update the off chain metadata this website can help with creating and uploading that, too.

If you want to update a larger amount of NFTs you should have a look at metaboss cli. Depending on which data you want to update exactly it has multiple functions to do so. If you want to change all the data use https://metaboss.rs/update.html#update-data-all if you want to update attributes or the image you will have to use a different tool like arloader to upload the json files though

A third possible solution is writing a script or website with the js sdk https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#update